# ASP.NET MVC - Window authentication with AD in System and Mobile

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, identity

How can I implement Windows authentication in an ASP.NET MVC website and retrieve the username from the currently logged-in Windows user?

In the context of an ASP.NET MVC Intranet website, how does Windows authentication operate on mobile devices, and how can the AD user information be accessed and utilized across various pages and controllers?

What steps should be taken to enable a user switching mechanism on a website with Windows authentication? Specifically, how can the current Windows user session be logged out upon switching to another user from the login page?

When a switched user logs out, what is the procedure for reverting to the Windows logged-in user on the website?

I am new to this intranet site please provide me idea

Comment: For mobile user, it depends on the bowser which the mobile used. But normally Windows Authentication works same with the PC browser. And it will store the user token inside the bowser to achieve cross page like PC browser.